# mimic dial pad of iphone inside your application

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am making an application which needs a dial pad to dial phone number from the app.
The iphone dial pad is great but could not get a way to mimic it inside my app.
The only way I think of doing it is putting the separate buttons for each number but then it looks very different from original dialpad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `UITextField`, you can set it's `keyboardType` property to show a number pad when the user focuses it.

```
UITextField *textField;
textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
```

`keyboardType` can be anything from this `enum`:

```
typedef enum {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).

    UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated

} UIKeyboardType;
```

Comment: this is a good option but I need to have a dial button.Since this keyboard comes from the bottom of the screen cannot find a way to do that.Is it possible to place custom button at the bottom of the screen with the keyboard.